# Conditionally render a react comp using switch case

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code just to simulate my problem. I would like to conditionally render a component on button click. Here is the code that I have, how do I render the component conditionally using a function and a switch case. Remember I am using only functional components and not class components.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import One from "./One";
import Two from "./Two";
import Three from "./Three";
import None from "./None";

import "./styles.css";
const handleRender = (e, props) => {
  let exp = Math.floor(Math.random() * props);
  console.log(exp);
  return exp;
};
function Test(exp) {
  switch (exp) {
    case 1:
      return <One />;
    case 2:
      return <Two />;
    case 3:
      return <Three />;
    default:
      return <None />;
  }
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={(e, p) => handleRender("a", "5")}>
        Render One Two or Three
      </button>
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-merkle-ln8wf

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with the App function below

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(null)
  const testNode = Test(state)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={(e, p) => setState(handleRender("a", "5"))}>
        Render One Two or Three
      </button>
      {testNode}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But, I wouldn't recommend this approach for such task

Comment: Why won't you recommend this approach though?

Comment: You build your test function like a component. But in fact, it's just a mapper. you can define your map object like this: const map = { case1: CompA, case2: CompB }. Then in render method, you can choose your component constructor like: const ConditionalComp = map[state]. And in return element you can just use <ConditionalComp />. In future, if you need to pass props to these components, you wouldn't need to pass them around.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a state:

```js
const handleRender = (e, props) => {
  let exp = Math.floor(Math.random() * props);
  console.log(exp);
  return exp;
};
function Test(exp) {
  switch (exp) {
    case 1:
      return <One />;
    case 2:
      return <Two />;
    case 3:
      return <Three />;
    default:
      return <None />;
  }
}
function App() {
  const [exp, setExp] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setExp(handleRender('a', '5'))}>
        Render One Two or Three
      </button>
      {Test(exp)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit stupefied-architecture-3q90r]

Comment: This solution makes sense to me!

Answer (score 1):

You could use hooks to keep track of the click, then conditionally render.

For example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// Your other imports.

function Test(exp) {
  switch (exp) {
    case 1:
      return <One />;
    case 2:
      return <Two />;
    case 3:
      return <Three />;
    default:
      return <None />;
  }
}

// this would be if you want to generate a random component
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function App() {
  const [renderedComponent, setRenderedComponent] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      // If you want a button for a particular component, you can
      // put in that number 1,2,3 instead of the call to randomIntFromInterval
      <button onClick={() => setRenderedComponent(randomIntFromInterval(1, 3))}>
        Render One Two or Three
      </button>
      {renderedComponent !== 0 && <Test />}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

This won't stop the button from being clicked again however, and possibly displaying another component. You'll have to introduce logic to handle that.